# Recovery disk for ASUS 1015 pem

Tags: netbook, hard-drive-recovery

When I purchased a ASUS 1015 pem netbook, the seller didn't provide a recovery disk.

How should I create a recovery disk??

Is it appropriate to use Acronis Recovery Manager or by pressing "f9" and inserting to recovery in boot time? Or other way?

I'm curious to lose "Express gate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F9 should start the recovery manager when using it at the start of boot up, this will wipe everything from the hard drive and reinstall it like it was when new.

Look for a program on the "all programs" menu "AI recovery burner" or similar, this will make the recovery DVD's.

Acronis RM is a 3rd party backup/recovery software that someone may have put on there.

The previous owner may have deleted the Asus recovery partition and media maker software, you would need to investigate further.

Comment: I bought it from the shop, so it's in its original state.. i entered to "recovery manager" with "f9" and i created a backup usb disk. **(1)** so, in future it is possible to use this usb disk to recover as it was bought that day. it will change to factory structure of netbook? **(2)** is this usb backup backs up "express gate"?? all parititon structure etc. **Thank you very much**

Comment: As far as I know it will restore all partitions and structures, so if the hard drive dies, you can install a blank hard drive and restore it just like it was originally. Your personal; data will be wiped though, so back up any personal data you have before restoring the PC. I would contact Asus support to make sure this is in fact the way it works.

Comment: So Asus is using Acronis to recover?, Interesting.